# Docker, update image or just use bind-mounts for website code?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using Django but I guess the question is applicable to any web project.

In our case, there are two types of codes, the first one being python code (run in django), and others are static files (html/js/css)

I could publish new image when there is a change in any of the code.
Or I could use `bind mounts` for the code. (For django, we could bind-mount the project root and static directory)

If I use `bind mounts` for code, I could just update the production machine (probably with `git pull`) when there's code change.

Then, docker image will handle updates that are not strictly our own code changes. (such as library update or new setup such as setting up elasticsearch) .

Does this approach imply any obvious drawback?

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons is advised to keep an operating system up to date with the last security patches but docker images are meant to be released in an immutable fashion in order we can always be able to reproduce productions issues outside production, thus the OS will not update itself for security patches being released. So this means we need to rebuild and deploy our docker image frequently in order to stay on the safe side.

So I would prefer to release a new docker image with my code and static files, because they are bound to change more often, thus requiring frequent release, meaning that you keep the OS more up to date in terms of security patches without needing to rebuild docker images in production just to keep the OS up to date.

Note I assume here that you release new code or static files at least in a weekly basis, otherwise I still recommend to update at least once a week the docker images in order to get the last security patches for all the software being used.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the more Docker-oriented solutions I've seen to this problem learn towards packaging the entire application in the Docker image.  That especially includes application code.

I'd suggest three good reasons to do it this way:

1. If you have a reproducible path to `docker build` a self-contained image, anyone can build and reproduce it.  That includes your developers, who can test a near-exact copy of the production system before it actually goes to production.  If it's a Docker image, plus this code from this place, plus these static files from this other place, it's harder to be sure you've got a perfect setup matching what goes to production.
2. Some of the more advanced Docker-oriented tools (Kubernetes, Amazon ECS, Docker Swarm, Hashicorp Nomad, ...) make it fairly straightforward to deal with containers and images as first-class objects, but trickier to say "this image plus this glop of additional files".
3. If you're using a server automation tool (Ansible, Salt Stack, Chef, ...) to push your code out, then it's straightforward to also use those to push out the correct runtime environment.  Using Docker to just package the runtime environment doesn't really give you much beyond a layer of complexity and some security risks.  (You could use Packer or Vagrant with this tool set to simulate the deploy sequence in a VM for pre-production testing.)

You'll also see a sequence in many SO questions where a Dockerfile COPYs application code to some directory, and then a `docker-compose.yml` bind-mounts the current host directory over that same directory.  In this setup the container environment reflects the developer's desktop environment and doesn't really test what's getting built into the Docker image.

("Static files" wind up in a gray zone between "is it the application or is it data?"  Within the context of this question I'd lean towards packaging them into the image, especially if they come out of your normal build process.  That especially includes the primary UI to the application you're running.  If it's things like large image or video assets that you could reasonably host on a totally separate server, it may make more sense to serve those separately.)